# Concat and merge dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, concatenation

How can we manipulate to obtain the expected dataset from the original dataset.

**Original dataset:**

```
|Subblock| Blocks |
|:-------|:------ |
|U       |CLON1177|
|Z       |CLON1177|
|A       |CLON1254|
|B       |CLON1254|
```

**Expected dataset:**

```
|Blocks  |Subblock|
|:-----  |:-------|
|CLON1177|U,Z     |
|CLON1254|A,B     |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following approach:

```
# import pandas library 
import pandas as pd 
  
# concatenate the string 
df['Subblock'] = df.groupby(['Blocks'])['Subblock'].transform(lambda x : ','.join(x)) 
  
# drop duplicate data 
df = df.drop_duplicates()    
  
# show the dataframe 
print(df)
```